# H10 error heroku

Tags: logging, heroku

have recently started using heroku 
the problem is the domain in heroku which shows my app works properly , when i click it it says your app works but when i use the command heroku logs it shows error H10

```
2017-05-11T21:07:10.338415+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-05-11T21:07:10.346065+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-05-11T21:07:10.279351+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app.js:15
2017-05-11T21:07:10.279375+00:00 app[web.1]:    throw new Error('missing FB_PAGE_TOKEN');
2017-05-11T21:07:10.279376+00:00 app[web.1]:    ^
2017-05-11T21:07:10.279377+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-05-11T21:07:10.279380+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
2017-05-11T21:07:10.279378+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
2017-05-11T21:07:10.279382+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
2017-05-11T21:07:10.279383+00:00 app[web.1]:     at startup (bootstrap_node.js:150:9)
2017-05-11T21:07:10.279377+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: missing FB_PAGE_TOKEN
2017-05-11T21:07:10.279379+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
2017-05-11T21:07:10.279381+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
2017-05-11T21:07:10.279382+00:00 app[web.1]:     at run (bootstrap_node.js:390:7)
2017-05-11T21:07:10.279384+00:00 app[web.1]:     at bootstrap_node.js:505:3
2017-05-11T21:07:10.279380+00:00 app[web.1]:     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
2017-05-11T21:07:10.279378+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/app.js:15:8)
2017-05-11T21:08:00.570314+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=tripneedbot.herokuapp.com request_id=c69012ea-674f-4201-851c-76c51e60cae5 fwd="151.100.102.79" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-05-11T21:08:01.044268+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=tripneedbot.herokuapp.com request_id=acdefb5e-ecd9-4a91-9ef8-322ec45d4eaa fwd="151.100.102.79" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-05-11T21:08:36.253657+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=tripneedbot.herokuapp.com request_id=72fc9b08-40f0-46be-9cc6-7f0e969f9fb3 fwd="151.100.102.79" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-05-11T21:08:36.577657+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=tripneedbot.herokuapp.com request_id=ea436bfd-46cf-4e9c-ad55-01df9ffb47d5 fwd="151.100.102.79" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-05-11T21:14:12.014981+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=tripneedbot.herokuapp.com request_id=33a1de6b-b8ec-4999-b408-79c2f3c1e98c fwd="151.100.102.79" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-05-11T21:14:11.816477+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=tripneedbot.herokuapp.com request_id=680fe9a2-0fe9-4854-9a6e-d503dc301b72 fwd="151.100.102.79" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-05-11T21:14:16.715499+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=tripneedbot.herokuapp.com request_id=21d8da6a-3d63-48e3-b899-ed427db25bd5 fwd="151.100.102.79" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2017-05-11T21:14:17.019983+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=tripneedbot.herokuapp.com request_id=e9741c4b-ec7a-4a03-ae94-8b50cd16c4c1 fwd="151.100.102.79" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2017-05-11T21:14:23.411319+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=tripneedbot.herokuapp.com request_id=78ed3a9d-065d-4114-855d-4717712f2246 fwd="151.100.102.79" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-05-11T21:14:23.854052+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=tripneedbot.herokuapp.com request_id=8e02ad0c-a483-4e56-9d8c-b4c557638215 fwd="151.100.102.79" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-05-11T21:22:11.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user pouya.sobhanipour@gmail.com
2017-05-11T21:22:23.001306+00:00 app[api]: Deploy ad4971a by user pouya.sobhanipour@gmail.com
2017-05-11T21:22:23.001306+00:00 app[api]: Release v4 created by user pouya.sobhanipour@gmail.com
2017-05-11T21:22:11.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2017-05-11T21:22:23.686183+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-05-11T21:22:25.544765+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2017-05-11T21:22:27.914022+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-05-11T21:22:27.915175+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-05-11T21:22:27.904561+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-05-11T21:22:27.839739+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app.js:27
2017-05-11T21:22:27.839765+00:00 app[web.1]:    throw new Error('missing SERVER_URL');
2017-05-11T21:22:27.839767+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-05-11T21:22:27.839766+00:00 app[web.1]:    ^
2017-05-11T21:22:27.839768+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/app.js:27:8)
2017-05-11T21:22:27.839768+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
2017-05-11T21:22:27.839767+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: missing SERVER_URL
2017-05-11T21:22:27.839770+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
2017-05-11T21:22:27.839771+00:00 app[web.1]:     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
2017-05-11T21:22:27.839772+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
2017-05-11T21:22:27.839769+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
2017-05-11T21:22:27.839772+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
2017-05-11T21:22:27.839774+00:00 app[web.1]:     at startup (bootstrap_node.js:150:9)
2017-05-11T21:22:27.839773+00:00 app[web.1]:     at run (bootstrap_node.js:390:7)
2017-05-11T21:22:27.839774+00:00 app[web.1]:     at bootstrap_node.js:505:3
2017-05-11T21:22:29.854813+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2017-05-11T21:22:32.403435+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-05-11T21:22:32.414007+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-05-11T21:22:32.331518+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app.js:27
2017-05-11T21:22:32.331531+00:00 app[web.1]:    throw new Error('missing SERVER_URL');
2017-05-11T21:22:32.331532+00:00 app[web.1]:    ^
2017-05-11T21:22:32.331533+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-05-11T21:22:32.331534+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: missing SERVER_URL
2017-05-11T21:22:32.331534+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/app.js:27:8)
2017-05-11T21:22:32.331535+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
2017-05-11T21:22:32.331536+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
2017-05-11T21:22:32.331536+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
2017-05-11T21:22:32.331537+00:00 app[web.1]:     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
2017-05-11T21:22:32.331537+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
2017-05-11T21:22:32.331538+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
2017-05-11T21:22:32.331539+00:00 app[web.1]:     at run (bootstrap_node.js:390:7)
2017-05-11T21:22:32.331539+00:00 app[web.1]:     at startup (bootstrap_node.js:150:9)
2017-05-11T21:22:32.331540+00:00 app[web.1]:     at bootstrap_node.js:505:3
2017-05-11T21:22:34.326565+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=tripneedbot.herokuapp.com request_id=9052bc7c-931a-4e6c-adbc-2d9f33f72499 fwd="151.100.102.79" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-05-11T21:22:34.024756+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=tripneedbot.herokuapp.com request_id=2d0ba84f-43e9-45d7-bcdc-40c63bbd4445 fwd="151.100.102.79" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-05-11T21:22:36.371863+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=tripneedbot.herokuapp.com request_id=7d74b84c-e038-43d4-ad90-9dd8c9bb7762 fwd="151.100.102.79" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-05-11T21:22:36.496076+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=tripneedbot.herokuapp.com request_id=8912a993-bec8-4d9d-9725-01208d633442 fwd="151.100.102.79" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-05-11T21:22:36.642595+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=tripneedbot.herokuapp.com request_id=bd85a326-bcb3-42f3-82a7-92c68e8b4d8d fwd="151.100.102.79" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-05-11T21:22:36.770562+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=tripneedbot.herokuapp.com request_id=68472a3b-dc15-4200-a26f-1b3e3dde77aa fwd="151.100.102.79" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-05-11T21:22:37.166121+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=tripneedbot.herokuapp.com request_id=eb7290ba-d2c5-4c73-bdfd-3461b39041e0 fwd="151.100.102.79" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-05-11T21:22:37.037447+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=tripneedbot.herokuapp.com request_id=d7d0af76-1866-48b4-9fb9-4573c6befff2 fwd="151.100.102.79" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-05-11T21:22:36.878664+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=tripneedbot.herokuapp.com request_id=083e9f62-ba63-413a-ab32-2fae4269bd96 fwd="151.100.102.79" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-05-11T21:22:37.310319+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=tripneedbot.herokuapp.com request_id=697457e1-705b-4982-ad7b-56d63dfe2502 fwd="151.100.102.79" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-05-11T21:22:37.740685+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=tripneedbot.herokuapp.com request_id=0b2e421f-f87b-45e9-963a-221bba8235b5 fwd="151.100.102.79" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-05-11T21:22:37.565491+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=tripneedbot.herokuapp.com request_id=1de0bfd2-d4d0-486f-a232-493c87c0791b fwd="151.100.102.79" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-05-11T21:22:37.654684+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=tripneedbot.herokuapp.com request_id=b8119aef-0de0-40a8-863d-0f6848435190 fwd="151.100.102.79" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-05-11T21:22:41.444514+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=tripneedbot.herokuapp.com request_id=6e3e4969-d127-4bc2-9e37-094c39dcde19 fwd="151.100.102.79" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-05-11T21:22:41.595738+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=tripneedbot.herokuapp.com request_id=d871dbc0-5100-4043-a810-858bbd2b28ec fwd="151.100.102.79" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-05-11T21:22:45.488015+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=tripneedbot.herokuapp.com request_id=cf3f66bc-b9eb-4e4a-8016-6435ed788ebd fwd="151.100.102.79" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-05-11T21:22:46.081446+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=tripneedbot.herokuapp.com request_id=1ee928f9-aee8-4355-9c80-94aa26bc1fc7 fwd="151.100.102.79" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-05-11T21:28:01.537909+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=tripneedbot.herokuapp.com request_id=260ffc3f-c7ba-435e-afe3-66a4f59b501b fwd="151.100.102.79" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-05-11T21:28:01.883136+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=tripneedbot.herokuapp.com request_id=364e0a64-28c3-47ac-980a-92654fd75132 fwd="151.100.102.79" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-05-11T21:29:24.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user pouya.sobhanipour@gmail.com
2017-05-11T21:29:35.618061+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 8a2ca79 by user pouya.sobhanipour@gmail.com
2017-05-11T21:29:35.618061+00:00 app[api]: Release v5 created by user pouya.sobhanipour@gmail.com
2017-05-11T21:29:24.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2017-05-11T21:29:36.214379+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-05-11T21:29:38.333348+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2017-05-11T21:29:40.834265+00:00 app[web.1]: running on port 22317
2017-05-11T21:29:41.972377+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2017-05-11T21:29:42.838607+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=tripneedbot.herokuapp.com request_id=5fff3886-3017-4490-ad6f-9e29692bfdd0 fwd="151.100.102.79" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=17ms status=200 bytes=228 protocol=https
2017-05-11T21:29:43.061835+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=tripneedbot.herokuapp.com request_id=6dc45634-0572-4e39-97bd-e6fb53490c3f fwd="151.100.102.79" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=8ms status=404 bytes=394 protocol=https
2017-05-11T21:30:45.786262+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/webhook/?

hub.mode=subscribe&hub.challenge=2010417633&hub.verify_token=2580403965Pouya" host=tripneedbot.herokuapp.com request_id=d5f57eff-ea3c-4c87-8bbe-5befe6221f55 fwd="31.13.113.172" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=9ms status=200 bytes=209 protocol=https
    2017-05-11T21:30:45.782703+00:00 app[web.1]: request
```

can you tell me what is the problem and how can i solve it 
i know that in the following i would have some problems with this

Comment: The variable FB_PAGE_TOKEN could not be accessed. Check if you imported it from where you are created it